# Sum of all values in a map in Dart

Tags: dart

I have a `Map<String, Map<String, double>> myMap = ...` and I would like to sum all the values in the second map. I have managed to do it like this

```
 double sum = 0;
 myMap.entries.forEach((element) {
 Map<String, double> map = element.value;
 sum += map.entries.map((e) => e.value).toList().fold(0, (a, b) => a + b);
 });
```

Is it possible to sum it using only one line without `.forEach()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, then an another option:

```
var sum = myMap.values.expand((e) => e.values).fold(0, (a, b) => a + b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one liner:

```
num sum = 0;
map.forEach((k, v) => v.forEach((kk, vv) => sum += vv));
```

Comment: It works but is there a way to formulate it without using a helper variable (sum)?

Comment: `num sum = map.values.reduce((a, b) => a + b));`  Be sure to learn fold and reduce.  They can come in handy!

Comment: @RandalSchwartz this doesen't work. I have a map inside a map.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to come up with the solution that works and all in one line.

```
double sum = myMap.values
        .map((e) => e.values)
        .fold(0, (a, b) => a + b.fold(0, (a, b) => a + b));
```